# Anchor tag mail functionality not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to add mail properties using jQuery, however jQuery is not getting triggered.

below is my anchor tag:

```
 <a href="" class="sendMail">share a friend</a>
```

mail part is constructed using below jQuery code. Please not this is implemented in view file of MVC controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.sendMail').click(function () {
            var email = '';
            var subject = '@Model.UserName' + 'has shared a snippet with you;
            var emailBody = '@Model.URL' + is the url;
            window.location.href = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + emailBody;
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Model.username and Model.url is the value coming from database
however mail part is not getting triggered. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default behavior of anchor's click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.sendMail').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //<-- Note here
            var email = '';
            var subject = '@Model.UserName' + 'has shared a snippet with you'; //<-- Missing closing quote
            var emailBody = '@Model.URL' + 'is the url';//<-- Missing opening & closing quote
            window.location.href = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + emailBody;
          //  return false; //<-- no need of this
        });
    });
</script>
```